# Quadratic variation of a multidimensional stochastic integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation

We consider the local martingale 
$$M_t:=\int_0^t F(X_s)dB_s $$
where $F:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^{d\times m} $ and $(B_t)_t$ is a m-dim. BM.

How can i calculate the quadratic variation?

I tried to calculate it using:

$[M,M]_t=(M_t)^2-2\int_0^tM_tdM_t  $

How can i calculate the second integral?

Comment: What do you mean when you write $M_t^2$? $M_t$ is a vector. I’m not even sure if there is a definition for multivariate quadratic variation in the manner you wrote. I think we have to define all the quadratic covariation for all combination for each component, kind of like how we define covariance matrix for multivariate Gaussian.

Comment: ah okay, so we have to define $[M^{(i)},M^{(j)}]_t$ first? And then?

Comment: $d[M^{i},M^{j}]_t=d[M^{i}]_td[M^{j}]_t=\sum_{k=1}^mF_{ik}(X_t)F_{jk}(X_t)dt$

Comment: Yes, and that’s all you can conclude from the givens. Also, quadratic variation is not what you tried to calculate, technically. Quadratic variation is usually denoted by angle brackets <M,M> and coincides with [M,M] if M is also continuous. Meaning if your F jumps crazily, M could be discontinuous with nonzero probability and [M,M] may be completely different from <M,M>.

Comment: @JamesYang At least if we are talking about the classical Itô theory, then $M$ is going to have continuous sample paths. It's one of the main properties of the stochastic integral wrt BM that the resulting process is going to have continuous sample paths.

Comment: @Thomas_R Find an increasing (nicely measurable) process $A_t$ such that $M_t^2-A_t^2$ is a local martingale. Then $A_t = [M]_t$.

Comment: @saz silly me, I forgot we’re working with Brownian for a sec. But I still think because M is a vector it doesn’t make much sense to find the quadratic variation in the usual way as you described.

Comment: @JamesYang Yeah, that's right; one has to do it for every component of the vector...